# Reliable path in graph

Tags: graphs

Suppose Bob has a messaging network (which is a graph), where a message travels from a vertex `V` to its adjacent vertex `U`. However, the messaging network is very unreliable, and the probability that the message sent from vertex `V` will fail to reach an adjacent vertex `U` is `PROBABILITY(U, V)`.

How to find a path where there is a minimal probability that a message will get lost on the path? What's the approach to this problem?

Comment: Try reducing this problem to *shortest path*. The logarithmic function could be useful here.

Comment: Have you considered enumerating all simple paths between the two vertices and multiplying the edges' probabilities of success for each path?

Comment: Nice exercise, but you should do your own exercises.  You might want to take another look at the textbook chapter / material you've been studying recently to see how you can apply it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @ChristopherBellII There can be exponentially many paths between two vertices, so this approach doesn't seem feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Given a path $u = x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n = v$, the probability that the message arrives is $p(x_0,x_1) \times p(x_1,x_2) \times \cdots \times p(x_{n-1},x_n)$, where $p(a,b)$ is the probability that the edge $(a,b)$ is "open". If you take a logarithm, then the product becomes a sum, and this reduces your problem to a more familiar one, shortest path.